# Bootstrap 3 - strange alignment of elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I load images in the loop to present thumbnails. You can see it [here](http://new.fitnesslaguna.pl/slowianska/galeria_zajecia_slowianska.html).

Everything looks good in Chrome, Opera and even in IE. But when you open it in Firefox one of the pictures in first section goes down, and there is gap between images.

For similar set of images in second section everything works fine.

Comment: It happens in Chrome too in smaller resolutions.

Comment: So is there any solution to avoid it ?

Comment: I think the grid classes should be placed on `<div>` tags and not on the `<a>` tag nor on the `<img>` tag, which is what I am seeing in your html code. Don't know if it would make a difference, but worth a shot.

Comment: Previously it was set to div element but the result was exactly the same

Comment: This is a consequence of the size of the images. Firefox's behaviour is correct. But it is not clear to me what your rules are for the dynamic adding of images. To make you your layout work, you will need to tightly control the image sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Remove padding:

```
.fl-photo-thumb {
    /*padding: 10px;*/
}
```

Try this code:

```
<div class="row" style="margin: 0px;">
    <a href="/gallery/600_7_1365087278.jpg" title="zajęcia mama i dziecko" class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 fl-photo-thumb">
        <img src="/gallery/600_7_1365087278.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Kliknij aby powiększyć" title="Kliknij aby powiększyć">
    </a>
    <a href="/gallery/600_7_1365087306.jpg" title="zajęcia mama i dziecko" class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 fl-photo-thumb">
        <img src="/gallery/600_7_1365087306.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Kliknij aby powiększyć" title="Kliknij aby powiększyć">
    </a>
    <a href="/gallery/600_7_1365087333.jpg" title="zajęcia mama i dziecko" class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 fl-photo-thumb">
        <img src="/gallery/600_7_1365087333.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Kliknij aby powiększyć" title="Kliknij aby powiększyć">
    </a>
    <a href="/gallery/600_7_1365087365.jpg" title="zajęcia mama i dziecko" class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 fl-photo-thumb">
        <img src="/gallery/600_7_1365087365.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Kliknij aby powiększyć" title="Kliknij aby powiększyć">
    </a>
    <a href="/gallery/600_7_1365087400.jpg" title="zajęcia mama i dziecko" class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 fl-photo-thumb">
        <img src="/gallery/600_7_1365087400.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Kliknij aby powiększyć" title="Kliknij aby powiększyć">
    </a>
    <a href="/gallery/600_7_1365087435.jpg" title="zajęcia mama i dziecko" class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 fl-photo-thumb">
        <img src="/gallery/600_7_1365087435.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Kliknij aby powiększyć" title="Kliknij aby powiększyć">
    </a>
    <a href="/gallery/600_7_1365087456.jpg" title="zajęcia mama i dziecko" class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 fl-photo-thumb">
        <img src="/gallery/600_7_1365087456.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Kliknij aby powiększyć" title="Kliknij aby powiększyć">
    </a>
    <a href="/gallery/600_7_1365087481.jpg" title="zajęcia mama i dziecko" class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 fl-photo-thumb">
        <img src="/gallery/600_7_1365087481.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Kliknij aby powiększyć" title="Kliknij aby powiększyć">
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Still the same :( and removing padding makes no spaces between images

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code and check

```
<div style="margin: 0px;" class="row">
    <a class="col-sm-2 fl-photo-thumb" title="zajęcia mama i dziecko" href="/gallery/600_7_1365087278.jpg">
        <img title="Kliknij aby powiększyć" alt="Kliknij aby powiększyć" class="img-responsive col-xs-12" src="/gallery/600_7_1365087278.jpg">
    </a>
    <a class="col-sm-2 fl-photo-thumb" title="zajęcia mama i dziecko" href="/gallery/600_7_1365087306.jpg">
        <img title="Kliknij aby powiększyć" alt="Kliknij aby powiększyć" class="img-responsive col-xs-12" src="/gallery/600_7_1365087306.jpg">
    </a>
    <a class="col-sm-2 fl-photo-thumb" title="zajęcia mama i dziecko" href="/gallery/600_7_1365087333.jpg">
        <img title="Kliknij aby powiększyć" alt="Kliknij aby powiększyć" class="img-responsive col-xs-12" src="/gallery/600_7_1365087333.jpg">
    </a>
    <a class="col-sm-2 fl-photo-thumb" title="zajęcia mama i dziecko" href="/gallery/600_7_1365087365.jpg">
        <img title="Kliknij aby powiększyć" alt="Kliknij aby powiększyć" class="img-responsive col-xs-12" src="/gallery/600_7_1365087365.jpg">
    </a>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="row">    
            <a class="col-sm-6 fl-photo-thumb" title="zajęcia mama i dziecko" href="/gallery/600_7_1365087400.jpg">
                <img title="Kliknij aby powiększyć" alt="Kliknij aby powiększyć" class="img-responsive col-xs-12" src="/gallery/600_7_1365087400.jpg">
            </a>
            <a class="col-sm-6 fl-photo-thumb" title="zajęcia mama i dziecko" href="/gallery/600_7_1365087435.jpg">
                <img title="Kliknij aby powiększyć" alt="Kliknij aby powiększyć" class="img-responsive col-xs-12" src="/gallery/600_7_1365087435.jpg">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="row">    
            <a class="col-sm-6 fl-photo-thumb" title="zajęcia mama i dziecko" href="/gallery/600_7_1365087456.jpg">
                <img title="Kliknij aby powiększyć" alt="Kliknij aby powiększyć" class="img-responsive col-xs-12" src="/gallery/600_7_1365087456.jpg">
            </a>
            <a class="col-sm-6 fl-photo-thumb" title="zajęcia mama i dziecko" href="/gallery/600_7_1365087481.jpg">
                <img title="Kliknij aby powiększyć" alt="Kliknij aby powiększyć" class="img-responsive col-xs-12" src="/gallery/600_7_1365087481.jpg">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Probably your code could work, but images are added dynamically and you can change it anytime. Therefor I can't use it as you presented above.